# Json to string in c#

Tags: c#, json, string, data-conversion

This JSON Data
http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo

how can i this

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");

TextBox1.Text = reader.tostring();
```

Comment: Json is not XML. Checkout Json.Net library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm happy with [this C# library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for JSON.

You can then write code like

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Examples.System.Net
{
    public class WebRequestGetExample
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            // Create a request for the URL. 
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
              "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
            // Parse JSON 
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);
            JArray status= (JArray)o["status"];
            string message = (string)status["message"];
            // Clean up the streams and the response.
            reader.Close ();
            response.Close ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my json string will be web serice.. how can i         `string json = http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo`

**string json = ?????**

Comment: see updated answer. Read up on HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse/WebClient

Answer (score 2):

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo");
TextBox1.Text = json;
```